# az acr build is always failing to run on windows

Tags: azure-cli

I have tried 3 ways now to run an `az acr build` command based on the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli) and all of them fail due to different reasons.

The command I'm attempting to run is the following...

```
az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1 --registry aksmattcloudgurutest --debug --verbose --file Dockerfile .
```

I'm on windows 10 and have Azure CLI version `2.29.1`

1. Via powershell 7.1.3

Get's stuck on `cli.azure.cli.command_modules.acr._archive_utils: Packing source code into tar to upload...`

After about 30 minutes it then fails with

```
cli.azure.cli.command_modules.acr._archive_utils: Packing source code into tar to upload...
cli.azure.cli.command_modules.acr.build: Deleting the archived source code from 'C:\Users\matty\AppData\Local\Temp\build_archive_c843a91f830e422cbd902644cd771393.tar.gz'...
cli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:
cli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/build.py", line 72, in acr_build
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 29, in upload_source_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 104, in _pack_source_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 210, in _archive_file_recursively
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 210, in _archive_file_recursively
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 210, in _archive_file_recursively
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 209, in _archive_file_recursively
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/build.py", line 80, in acr_build
knack.util.CLIError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
az_command_data_logger: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
```

2. Via Git Bash

Fails with

```
←[93mcli.azure.cli.command_modules.acr._archive_utils: Packing source code into tar to upload...←[0m
←[36mcli.azure.cli.command_modules.acr.build: Deleting the archived source code from 'C:\Users\matty\AppData\Local\Temp\build_archive_52fe8aedfaec484283d68703ffcdef11.tar.gz'...←[0m
←[36mcli.azure.cli.core.util: azure.cli.core.util.handle_exception is called with an exception:←[0m
←[36mcli.azure.cli.core.util: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/build.py", line 72, in acr_build
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 29, in upload_source_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 104, in _pack_source_code
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 210, in _archive_file_recursively
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 210, in _archive_file_recursively
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/_archive_utils.py", line 209, in _archive_file_recursively
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\Com\\dmp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\knack/cli.py", line 231, in invoke
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 657, in execute
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 720, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 691, in _run_job
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 328, in __call__
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/acr/build.py", line 80, in acr_build
knack.util.CLIError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\Com\\dmp'
←[0m
←[91mcli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\Com\\dmp'←[0m
←[91maz_command_data_logger: [WinError 5] Access is denied: '.\\Com\\dmp'←[0m
←[36mcli.knack.cli: Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x03B631D8>]←[0m
←[32maz_command_data_logger: exit code: 1←[0m
←[32mcli.__main__: Command ran in 11.177 seconds (init: 0.210, invoke: 10.967)←[0m
←[32mtelemetry.save: Save telemetry record of length 2990 in cache←[0m
←[93mtelemetry.check: Negative: The C:\Users\matty\.azure\telemetry.txt was modified at 2021-10-21 15:52:56.963771, which in less than 600.000000 s←[0m
```

3. Via Cloud Shell

Fails with

```
2021/10/21 14:23:07 Output from dependency scanning: fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
unable to understand line FROM
failed to run step ID: build: failed to scan dependencies: exit status 1

Run ID: db2 failed after 4s. Error: failed during run, err: exit status 1
```

The contents of my `Dockerfile` is simply `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/hello-world`

I have the following environment

- Windows 10
- Azure CLI 2.29.1
- Powershell 7.1.3
- Azure Cloud Shell
- Git Bash

Should it be this hard just to run a quickstart?

Comment: Could you please refer this https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/2329

Comment: That doesn't appear to be related to my issues. I can run `az --version` without any issues. I'm not attempting to run a self hosted agent. I'm simply attempting to use the azure cli on a windows 10 machine

Answer (score 2):

Can't answer all the issues I'm having but part of the problem was the command...

```
echo FROM mcr.microsoft.com/hello-world > Dockerfile
```

Creates the FROM command on 2 lines when using powershell.

[image]

Either using bash or editing the `Dockerfile` to make sure it is all on one line in cloud shell version worked for me.

Comment: For those like me that are completely new to this thought it might be worth writing down the steps.

1. type `echo FROM mcr.microsoft.com/hello-world > Dockerfile`
2. type `code Dockerfile`
3. An editor will open. Remove the new line
4. Press `ctrl+s` to save the file
5. Press `ctrl+q` to quit the editor
6. The command `az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1 --registry <myContainerRegistry> --file Dockerfile .` should now work

Answer (score 0):

We have tested in our local environment by following the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-quickstart-task-cli) steps that you have shared .

By running the below `az acr build`  we are successfully able to build an image & pushed it to the acr registry .

```
 $ az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1 --registry ajaymtRegistry --verbose --file Dockerfile . --debug
```

Here are some of the output screenshot for your reference :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note**: Our portal cloud shell is running with az version  `2.29.0` as shown below

[image]

Comment: Still didn't work for me. `echo FROM mcr.microsoft.com/hello-world > Dockerfile` creates a multi line `Dockerfile` for me when it should be a single line.